# Backend service for ionic push

Tags: ionic-framework, backend, pushwoosh

I have implemented ionic push notifications using pushwoosh. But there I use the dashboard which has provided by pushwoosh to send push notifications. I wanted to send push notifications using a back end which has created by my self. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

i am working on ionic-framework and also using push notification to sent notification via **REST API** using [node-gcm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm) its working fine.
**sample code**

```
(function() {
function execute(rqst, q, fwk) {
    var gcm = require('node-gcm');

    var message = new gcm.Message();
    message.timeToLive = 3000;
    message.addData({
        title: 'Push Notification Sample',
        body: 'Abnormal data access',
        icon: 'ic_launcher',
        message: '"\u270C Peace, Love \u2764 and PhoneGap \u2706!'
    });
    message.addNotification({
        title: 'Push Notification Sample',
        body: 'Abnormal data access',
        icon: 'ic_launcher',
        message: 'hey , how are you?'
    });


    /* message.addData('message', "\u270C Peace, Love \u2764 and PhoneGap \u2706!");

     message.addData('title', 'Push Notification Sample');

     message.addData('msgcnt', '3');*/
    // Duration in seconds to hold in GCM and retry before timing out. Default 4 weeks (2,419,200 seconds) if not specified.

    // Set up the sender with you API key
    var sender = new gcm.Sender('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-hK5wE');

    // Add the registration IDs of the devices you want to send to

    var registrationIds = [];
    registrationIds.push('APA91bEWB6-xcrfrfrffr-LqyMohLP4T-XuydQgt44Q6Acw5kmVDWvAaOsm1CriASm02SyBceZ2NBWF4FIES7grcPeY5v4fLQme2UqhRteeWRdD_Ma25QMGESOGAyw_Uhgg_EjkTl-');


    // Send the message
    // ... trying only once sendNoRetry

    sender.send(message, {
        registrationIds: registrationIds
    }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            q.resolve({
                status: 200,
                data: {
                    data: err,
                    code: 1
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            q.resolve({
                status: 200,
                data: result
            });
        }
    });

}
return exports.execute = execute;
})();
```

Comment: I'm new to push notifications. So, are you initiating this javascript code from your REST API? How would the user get this push notification if they do not launch the app? Can you explain how you send these push notifications out of the REST Svc? That is what I'm needing to do as well.